# Understanding Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to understand the concept of linked lists. So far this is what I know and where I'm having problems to understand.

```
//create node
struct list
{
int id; //member var
list* next; //pointer to link next list item
}

//int main()

//create list head and set it to NULL
list* head = NULL;

//instantiate list node
list* newList = new list;

//insert a list
newList->id = 20;
newList->next = NULL;
```

This I do not really understand what's going on.

```
newList->next = head;
head = newList;
```

Comment: YOU DON'T USE `new` IN C++!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Okay. SO How do I dynamically allocate space?

Comment: what specifically don't you understand? Why it is being done? What is being done? How? When? Where? Who?

Comment: by malloc you can allocate space

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: stop talking rubbish. if you want to give good practice advices, please phrase your sentences accordingly.

Comment: If you are stuck this early, it might help more to find a good book or tutorial on C++ data structures.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath 98% of what you really actually need is provided with [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and [Container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) in the current c++ standard library. So what are you bothering about? There are really rare use cases to use `new` or `new[]` (and the according `delete`/`delete[]` statements) directly, the one the OP's pointing about isn't one of them.

Comment: @sasha NO! `malloc` is for evil void pointers from C, not C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if you are implementing a linked list as part of learning about data structures and the algorithms that go with them (which seems to be the case here), then pointers and dynamically allocated memory pretty much goes along with that.

Comment: @crashmstr [I have my doubts](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/software-development-in-wild-i-have.html) this should be a topic of learning basic c++ data structures, besides the advanced courses, certainly not for beginners. As far I experience the _beginner_ questions coming up here, it doesn't seems to be well established practice in many universities to teach _the right and straight forward things 1st_ and not leave their students with a wrongly biased perception, which benefits c++ you can actually profit about.

Comment: ... Well, this would require some more efforts from the lecturer's sides. Lazy pack :P ...

Comment: have a look at http://pastebin.com/egDECvDi

Comment: @d14 Your code shown, doesn't do any really sensible operation to maintain a singly linked list. Return to your text book to read what operations you actually need.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think one should really distinguish between `new` and `new[]`. It's the latter which must be avoided. I don't see how or why you would avoid `new` in situations where `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` do not solve your problem or just complicate it. And of course, let's not forget about placement new, which is needed to implement allocators for containers.

Comment: @ChristianHackl _"It's the latter which must be avoided."_ No, you avoid to use either in modern c++. _" And of course, let's not forget about placement new, which is needed to implement allocators for containers"_ Placement new has it's use cases, but certainly not falling into that 98% range I've estimated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: A better guideline would be "avoid dynamic allocation", followed by "understand the costs and benefits of smart pointers". As an example, `new` is still the easiest way to go if you need a dynamically allocated object which should never be destroyed at all (such as an instance of a logger class). You could probably get around this problem by using `std::unique_ptr` with a no-op deleter, but what's the point? For `new[]`, on the other hand, I cannot imagine *any* useful application.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: telling me all this is totally counter-productive... I guess you're probably going to advise this to many posters, so if you want to help them, *please* phrase a good *advice* once (and not a strict rule which will confuse the *censored* out of beginners - FYI their books are likely full of `new`) and copy-paste it each time you need it. Or, if you prefer, you can post a Q&A and link that. I hope you won't continue this discussion with *me* because then you've completely missed my point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE:** The memory "locations" I will reference in this answer are there purely for example are not meant to mimic the actual location these pointers might or might not ever point to.

Draw these relationships out on paper to visualize the results. Let's break it down by lines.

```
list *head = NULL;
```

And here is our visualization:

```
 *head (0x00)
+-----------+
|           |
|   NULL    |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Now, we follow these next lines:

```
list *newList = new list;
newList->id = 20;
newList->next = NULL;
```

And that visualization:

```
 *head (0x00)      *newList (0x3a)
+-----------+     +----+------+
|           |     | id | next |
|   NULL    |     +----+------+
|           |     | 20 | NULL |
+-----------+     +----+------+
```

And finally we end with your last bit:

```
newList->next = head;
```

And that alters the visualization thusly (reordered for clarity):

```
 *newList (0x3a) +->*head (0x00)
+----+------+    | +-----------+
| id | next |    | |           |
+----+------+    | |   NULL    |
| 20 | head------+ |           |
+----+------+      +-----------+
```

This has created the "link" that gives a LinkedList it's name. You link nodes together by some form of a reference. So what you've done is created a "head" or beginning of the list, and then you've created a secondary node in the list and placed it (logically) before head. Normally you'd then reassign your reference to `newList` to `head` since it's the new beginning of the list.

The next step would likely be (and I'm sure this what you meant with the erroneous bit that I ask about at the end of this question):

```
head = newList;
```

Which now changes the visualization to this:

```
 *head (0x3a)  +---> (0x00)
+----+------+  |   +-----------+
| id | next |  |   |           |
+----+------+  |   |   NULL    |
| 20 | 0x00----+   |           |
+----+------+      +-----------+
```

Also, what about the following line?

```
head = n; // What is 'n'? Where did you get it from? It doesn't appear anywhere else in your sample
```

**EDIT**

I altered the visualization to more accurately reflect what would be realistic. I wasn't paying attention to what I was doing when I posted the original answer so many thanks to José and his comment for bringing it to my attention the visualization was inaccurate.

In addition to altering the visuals I added a bit more information and wanted to take it a step further in saying that here's how you would use this linked list to loop over it's records.

```
list *node = head;
while (node != NULL) {
    std::cout << "The id is " << node->id << std::endl;
    node = node->next;
}
```

Comment: n was a typo, I fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this list `*head = NULL;` isn't creating anything, merely declaring a pointer and making it point to nowhere. But no object is created here.

Comment: @JoséErnestoLaraRodríguez Fixed the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
newList->next = head;
head = newList;
```

You start out with `head` set to NULL.
Then, you create a new node and let its next point to `head`, which is NULL.
Then, you set `head` to be the new node. Now, head points to a list that has one item in it.